# Code crashing at SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress

Tags: ios, swift

My code is crashing at the function shown below. The function is used to check if I have internet access. I was wondering what the crash means and how to prevent it?

```
func connectionStatus() -> ReachabilityStatus {
    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    guard let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress, {
        SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
    }) else {
        return .Unknown
    }

    var flags : SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = []
    if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) {
        return .Unknown
    }

    return ReachabilityStatus(reachabilityFlags: flags)
}
```

[image: connnectionStatus]